# Making a new Object with inputs

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

I am trying to make like a little website that just shows what you wrote in the input and stores it.
Like a recipe website where everyone can post their own recipees.

```js
let InputTitle = document.getElementById('title').value
let InputSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value
let InputText = document.getElementById('text').value
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')
let div = document.querySelector('div')
let num = 5

class Book {
  constructor(title, subject, text) {
    this.title = title
    this.subject = subject
    this.text = text
  }
}

const userBook = new Book(InputTitle, InputSubject, InputText)

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(userBook);

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Truc</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Entrez votre titre.">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Entrez votrez sujet">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea id="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Entrez votre texte"></textarea>
  <button id="btn">Submit</button>
  <div></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to make a new object and using the inputs as arguments.
But in the console it shows me this:

```
Book {title: '', subject: '', text: ''}
subject: ""
text: ""
title: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: You're getting the input values and creating the `Book` object when the page first loads, before the user has entered any values. You need to move all that code into the click listener.

Comment: `let InputTitle = document.getElementById('title').value` is the value at that moment in time. It does not keep updating as the user changes the value.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with your code. However, there are a few modifications you need to make in order to achieve your desired functionality. Here's an updated version of your code.

In the updated code, the `displayRecipe` function creates a new `<div>` element and sets its **HTML** content to display the **recipe information**. The `recipeList` element is used as a container to store and display the recipes.

When the user clicks the "**Submit**" `<button>`, the event listener is triggered. It retrieves the input values, creates a new Book object, and then calls the `displayRecipe` function to show the recipe on the webpage.

Make sure to place this code in a JavaScript file called **script.js** *(Or whatever you want to call it)* and ensure that the file is **properly linked in your HTML file** which I do in the updated code.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let recipeList = document.getElementById('recipeList');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let inputTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;
  let inputSubject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
  let inputText = document.getElementById('text').value;

  const userBook = new Book(inputTitle, inputSubject, inputText);
  displayRecipe(userBook);

// Log the book object
  console.log(userBook);
});

class Book {
  constructor(title, subject, text) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.text = text;
  }
}

function displayRecipe(recipe) {
  let recipeElement = document.createElement('div');
  recipeElement.innerHTML = `
    <h3>${recipe.title}</h3>
    <p><strong>Subject:</strong> ${recipe.subject}</p>
    <p>${recipe.text}</p>
    <hr>
  `;
  recipeList.appendChild(recipeElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Truc</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Entrez votre titre.">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Entrez votre sujet">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <textarea id="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Entrez votre texte"></textarea>
  <button id="btn">Submit</button>
  <div id="recipeList"></div>

<!--Link your file like this -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
  </html>
```